# Select single value from ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am passing ViewBag like,

```
 var forms = SqlMapper.Query(con, "getDetails", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

 ViewBag.myForm = forms;
```

This 'forms'  contains values like VehicleType, VehicleName, VehiclePrice
and I am displaying those in the view using loop,

```
  @foreach (var frm in ViewBag.myForm)
  {
  <div class="form-group">

  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">@frm.VehicleType</label>
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">@frm.VehicleName</label>
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">@frm.VehiclePrice</label>
  </div>
  }
```

This works fine. Now I want to display VehicleType in the header as well. And I don't want to loop the ViewBag again to get the VehicleType. VehicleType will be same for the list. Like if I get 'Car' as VehicleType, then for that ViewBag, 'Car' is the only VehicleType. How can I read VehicleType without looping ViewBag? Thanks

To get more idea on data,

```
Vehicle Type | Name | Price
Car          | Ford | 1000000
Car          | Audi | 1500000
Car          | Chev.| 1250000
Car          | Volks| 1246000
```

I want to display the Vehicle type,

```
 <div class="box-header with-border">
                        <h3 class="box-title">@ViewBag.myForm ----- VehicleType</h3>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a model instead of ViewBag.That way you won't have to loop through the list to get one `VehicleType`

**Vehicle.cs**

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public int VehicleID {get; set;}
    public string VehicleType {get; set;}
    public string VehicleName {get; set;}
    public double VehiclePrice {get; set;}
}
```

**Controller**

```
var forms = SqlMapper.Query(con, "getDetails", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
List<Vehicle> vehicleList = new List<Vehicle>();
vehicleList = forms;
```

**View**

```
    @model IEnumerable<ProjName.Models.Vehicle> 

    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ElementAt(0).VehicleType)
    @foreach (var frm in Model)
    {
    <div class="form-group">

        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">@frm.VehicleName</label>
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">@frm.VehiclePrice</label>
    </div>
    }
```

Comment: Agreed on model approach. Just curious with ViewBag...Is it not possible?

Comment: It is possible but not encourage as ViewBag is more suitable to store temporary data. Once you do a redirection you will lost your ViewBag data as it is only available during the life-cycle of HTTP request.You can read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186674/viewbag-viewdata-lifecycle) to get a better understanding. Cheers! :-)