# ViewBag.Message not showing ASP.NET MVC c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a view named Index.cshtml and controller named HomeController and I can't seem to show the ViewBag.Message and ViewBag.FileUrl to the view. The code is working I just can't show the ViewBag.message when the file is successfully uploaded.

Here's my code below

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{ 
ViewBag.Title = "Upload a file to S3 Bucket";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>
<h3>@ViewBag.FileUrl</h3>

<p>Use this area to browse image and upload to S3 bucket.</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<div>
    @Html.TextBox("file", "", new { type = "file" }) <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    @ViewBag.FileUrl
    @ViewBag.Message
</div>
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(accesskey, secretkey, bucketRegion);
    var result = "";
    var keyName = file.FileName;
    var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);

    try
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
            var fileTransferUtilityRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                FilePath = filePath,
                StorageClass = S3StorageClass.StandardInfrequentAccess,
                PartSize = 6291456, // 6 MB.  
                Key = keyName,
                CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
            };

            fileTransferUtilityRequest.Metadata.Add("param1", "Value1");
            fileTransferUtilityRequest.Metadata.Add("param2", "Value2");
            fileTransferUtility.Upload(fileTransferUtilityRequest);
            fileTransferUtility.Dispose();
        }
        result = string.Format("http://{0}.s3.amazonaws.com/{1}", bucketName, keyName);

        ViewBag.FileUrl = result;
        ViewBag.Message = "File Uploaded Successfully!!";
    }
    catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Error occurred: " + amazonS3Exception.Message;
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186674/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing redirect the result so that value becomes null, instead of that use `Tempdata` in where assign a value and get it where you redirect,

```
catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
{
    Tempdata["Message"]="Error occurred: " + amazonS3Exception.Message;
}
```

and `Index` action method, try it like below ,

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message= (string)Tempdata["Message"]
    return View();
}
```

Comment: You need to spell correctly: `TempData` (with a **capital D** ) - not "Tempdata" - correct spelling is **important** and relevant in C# / ASP.NET MVC !

Comment: This worked! Thanks! :) I'm new to asp.net mvc so I get confused sometimes :)

Answer (score 3):

You assign `ViewBag` values, which are lost by the subsequent `RedirectToAction()`.

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9186855/21336), with [detailed comparison of ViewData, ViewBag, and TempData](https://rachelappel.com/2014/01/02/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp-net-mvc-3-applications/). In your case, `TempData` should work.