# Display message when user clicks on "Add To Cart" button in ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am creating a shopping website in ASP.NET MVC.

What I want to do is display a message "Your products are added to cart" when the user clicks on the "Add To Cart" button. I don't know how to redirect on any page I just show a message.

Here is my controller

```
public ActionResult AddtoCart(int id)
{
    List<Product> list;

    if (Session["MyCart"] == null)
    { 
        list = new List<Product>();
    }
    else
    { 
        list = (List<Product>)Session["MyCart"]; 
    }

    list.Add(db.Products.Where(p => p.Product_ID == id).FirstOrDefault());
    Session["MyCart"] = list;

    list[list.Count - 1].Pro_Quantity = 1;
    ViewBag.cart = list.Count();

    Session["count"] = Convert.ToInt32(Session["count"]) + 1;

    return RedirectToAction("Shop", "Home");
}
```

Here is my "Add to Cart" button:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("AddtoCart","Home", new {id=p.Product_ID })" class="filled-button">
    Add to Cart
</a>
```

Comment: You say you don't know how to redirect....yet you have a clear RedirectToAction result that you're returning. Have you considered passing some sort of message there as part of the URL? Perhaps your query string could include something like `?productadded=1` and then on the page the user is redirected to, check for the presence of that query string. If present, show the message. That seems pretty straightforward. Can you give that a try?

Comment: you send ajax request when add to cart button clicked and return a message from your action result instead of redirection. base the message returned back you can show it to user.

Comment: Can you Please edit my code and show me how i can do it?

Comment: Do you want the page to not jump when adding to the shopping cart, and only display information "Your products are added to cart"on the current page?

Comment: Yes Exaclty Can You please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common way to accomplish that is to add a value to the `ViewBag` in your controller action, then in the view that action returns, check whether that `ViewBag` value is set, and if so display your message.

*However*, the `ViewBag` only lasts for the duration of a single request. A `Redirect` or `RedirectToAction` is a *new* request. To send data between one request and another in MVC, you have to use `TempData` instead.

(If you want to learn more about when `ViewBag` and `TempData` are used and their lifecycles, see [ViewBag/ViewData Lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186674/viewbag-viewdata-lifecycle)).

So since your controller action returns `RedirectToAction`, you have to use `TempData` in the first action. So in your `AddToCart` action, you'd add:

```
TempData["ItemAdded"] = true;
```

Then, in the `Shop` action, you can pick up that `TempData` value and use it to set a value in the `ViewBag` so it can be displayed in the view.

So in your `Shop` action, you can add something like this:

```
if (TempData.ContainsKey("ItemAdded") && (bool)TempData["ItemAdded"])
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your products are added to cart";
}
```

Finally, in your `Shop` view, you'd do something like this:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewBag.Message))
{
    <div class="message">
        @ViewBag.Message
    </div>
}
```

---

## Edit - to address comment about wanting a pop-up message

If you want to update the current page without navigating away, you're going to have to use AJAX.

Here's two simple ways of accomplishing that. Which one you choose depends on whether you've already got a form on the page, how you've accomplished things elsewhere in this project, how your company prefers things to be done, etc.

#### 1) Using jQuery `$.ajax()`

In your View, you'll want to change your button to something like this:

```html
<a class="filled-button" onclick="addToCart(event, '@(p.Product_ID)')">
    Add to Cart
</a>
<!-- or -->
<button type="button" class="filled-button" onclick="addToCart('@(p.Product_ID)')">
    Add to Cart
</button>
```

(You can, of course, assign the click events inside your `$(document).ready` function, rather than using the `onclick` attribute.)

Also in your View, you'll add some JavaScript like this:

```js
var addToCartUrl = "@Url.Action("AddtoCart", "Home")";

// you only need the productId parameter if you're not passing in the event
function addToCart(e, productId) {
    // prevent navigating away from the page on <a> tag click
    e.preventDefault();

    // make ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: addToCartUrl,
        data: { id: productId },
        success: function (data) {
            // display your message however you want
        }
    });
}
```

In your Controller Action:

```csharp
// change the last line from:
// return RedirectToAction("Shop", "Home");
// to:
return Json("Your products are added to cart", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

#### 2) Using MVC's built-in ajax form

This method isn't that drastically different from the previous method.

First, you'll surround the product section of your View with a form, like so:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddtoCart", "Home", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "productAddedToCart" }))
{
    ...
}
```

And you'll change your "Add to Cart" buttons to `submit` buttons:

```html
<button type="submit" name="id" value="@(p.Product_ID)" class="filled-button">
    Add to Cart
</button>
```

Just like method #1, you'll need to return JSON from your Controller Action:

```csharp
// from: return RedirectToAction("Shop", "Home");
return Json("Your products are added to cart", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Finally, the `OnSuccess` JavaScript function will look just like it did in method 1:

```js
function productAddedToCart (data) {
    // display your message however you want
}
```

Comment: Yes it is working But actually I want a Pop up message ?

Comment: Thanks I have applied your it is Working But it doesn't show Products in Cart suddenly until I refresh the page Manually...
I am using Session to Add Products in cart..........

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you also want to update the number of items in the cart on the page with that ajax call? If so, you just have to return an object in your JSON rather than just a string.

Comment: Yes You Understand Correctly Can You tell me How i Can do it? How i can return string and object both?

Comment: @KamranAli you don't return both a string and object, you just create an anonymous object and return that as JSON. `return Json({ message = "Your products ...", cartCount = 5 })`